# How to securely connect Google Apps Script to Azure SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script, azure-sql-database

I'm reluctant to connect to use getConnection from within GAS to connect to Azure SQL Database, as I'm not sure the connection would be encrypted. Since it's sensible data I want to pull from GAS, I'd like to have it go through encrypted connection but I don't know how to achieve it? Are at least credentials encrypted when authenticating? What damage can a man in the middle do?

Would I have ore secure options if I would host the Database on non-Azure SQL Server? getConnection provides _serverSslCertificate, _clientSslCertificate and _clientSslKey, but I don't think they can be used on Azure SQL Server, right?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String)

Answer (score 1):

Connections to Azure SQL Database are always encrypted.

And you can test trustServerCertificate is off by connecting with the IP address instead of the FQDN.  With trustServerCertificate=false, the connection will fail unless you connect with the FQDN.  The error should look something like:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
>   error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)

"All connections to Azure SQL Database require encryption (SSL/TLS) at all times while data is "in transit" to and from the database"

from: **[Securing your SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview)**

Comment: In your link it says: "In your application's connection string, you must specify parameters to encrypt the connection and not to trust the server certificate, otherwise the connection will not verify the identity of the server and will be susceptible to "man-in-the-middle" attacks". 

My question was: how do I avoid man-in-the-middle attacks?

Comment: The connection will always be encrypted, but you must set trustServerCertificate to false to prevent MITM attacks.  The connection string parameters for the Microsoft JDBC drivers are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties

Comment: But it seems like Google implementation of JDBC doesn't support trustServerCertificate flag, so I sent know how to avoid mitm situation. They only support the flags specified in the link I gave.

Comment: I don't know about Google's stuff.  But note that a MITM attack here would require compromising either Google's or Microsoft's DNS servers.

Comment: Also trustServerCertificate defaults to false, so if you can't set it, you may get the behavior you desire.

Comment: David, wasn't there an incident last month when part of the traffic got rerouted through Russian site? Another question: is there a danger of sniffing from within Google Cloud? I mean, in case of subnet  misconfiguration, someone running a VM in Google Cloud could sniff on packets going from Google Apps to Azure, right?